# Web.xml доступ и изменение

Tags: tomcat, web.xml

Требуется, в зависимости от содержимого web.xml запускать те илииные сервисы приложения. Как на runtime менять содержимое web.xml?

Comment: первая и вторая фразы вопроса, насколько я понимаю, являются независимыми несвязанными вопросами. здесь такие вопросы принято задавать по-отдельности.

Comment: Нет вопрос , один. Как на runtime менять web.xml. для чего? Первая часть вопроса конкретизирует для чего

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел ответ. Если не программировать используя политики безопасности, то можно просто менять одну строчку в  файле catalina.policy(для tomcat) на следующую:
// The permissions granted to the context WEB-INF/classes directory
**grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/Yours__Application /WEB-INF/classes/-**" {
// };
надо просто снять комменты с указанной строки.